# javascript find string from input

Tags: javascript

I made a chatbot in html/css/js using the switch method. I'm wondering how can I find a specific string from the user input. Any help is appreciated!
example:
usr input "what is the **fee**"

```
let theMsg = document.getElementById('theMsg');
let sendMsg = document.getElementById('sendMsg');
sendMsg.addEventListener('click', function(){
    userSend()
    switch(theMsg.value){
        case 'fee':
            feeResponse();
            break;
```

Comment: you can use strings includes method https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: `.indexOf()` would be safer

Comment: PS: Don't *just* use `let` as a cooler replacement for `var`. Learn about the differences from `let` and `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a *dictionary* Object where the propertyName is the keyword you're interested in for printing a desired message:

```js
const responsesDictionary = {
  fee: "Fee is similar to Foo",
  bar: "Bar is almost like Baz",
  foo: "Foo is the grandad of Fee",
  "a z": "The alphabet",
};

const EL_theMsg  = document.querySelector("[name=theMsg]");
const EL_sendMsg = document.querySelector('#sendMsg');

const words = Object.keys(responsesDictionary).join("|");
const rgx = new RegExp(`\\b(${words})\\b`, "ig");

const getResponse = () => {
  const msg = EL_theMsg.value.toLowerCase();
  const matches = msg.match(rgx) || [];
  const response = matches.map(word => responsesDictionary[word]);
  console.log(response.join("\n"));
};

EL_sendMsg.addEventListener("click", getResponse);
```

```html
Insert some text and use one of the words: "fee", "bar" or "foo".<br>Hit SEND for some magic<br>

<input name="theMsg" type="text" value="Test default foo message bar">
<button id="sendMsg">SEND</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple you can check if it's in the message by just doing

Example:
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.includes("world");

I don't know how you wanna implement it. Get back to me if you have any questions

Comment: The includes() method is case sensitive. One might use `"Fee"` and voilà you have a bug.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you only just need to do `str.toLowerCase().includes(value)`. Change the case of the user input before calling .includes

Comment: you mean `.includes(valueLowercase)` ;)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to find a particular word from a string. You can use `String.includes`

```js
let stringHasFee = theMsg.value.toLowerCase().includes("fee")

switch(stringHasFee) {
   case true:
     // user input has "fee" 
     feeResponse();
     break;
   case false:
     anotherResponse();
     break;
   default: 
     defaultResponse();
}
```